# Вариативные шаблоны

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
long double sum(const T& val)
{
    return static_cast<long double>(val);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
long double sum(const T& val, const Args&... args)
{
    return static_cast<long double>(val) + sum(args...);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << sum(1, 2.0, 3.0L, 4.0f, 5ULL) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

который компилируется и выполняется без ошибок. Но стоит изменить порядок определений функций, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
long double sum(const T& val, const Args&... args)
{
    return static_cast<long double>(val) + sum(args...);
}

template <typename T>
long double sum(const T& val)
{
    return static_cast<long double>(val);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << sum(1, 2.0, 3.0L, 4.0f, 5ULL) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

и сразу получаем ошибки компиляции, что нет подходящих перегрузок и что `sum` ожидает два аргумента, а получает ноль аргументов. Почему так присходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором случае перегрузка `sum`, принимающая один аргумент (и тем самым самым останавливающая рекурсию на шаге вызова `sum` с одним аргументом) еще не является объявленной в при вызове `sum(args...)`, соответственно рекурсия завершается ошибкой на шаге вызова `sum` без аргументов.

Comment: Что-то я уже туплю вечерем... Спасибо! И еще вопрос. Когда создаются функции из шаблона, то код будет содержать столько функций, сколько аргументов мы передадим ей? Т.е. мой код будет в итоге сожержать 5 функций `sum`?

Comment: Все как всегда, но помогает старый совет с шаблонами. Разделять определение и объявление и делать все это в хедерфайлах )))

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup Это уж как компилятор наоптимизирует… Ну а вообще такого рода рекурсивных шаблонов следует избегать, в данном случае в рекурсии и во второй перегрузке с одним аргументом нет никакой необходимости.